# Why is it possible to override both __eq__ and __ne__ in classes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

Python provides the feature of overloading `==` operator AND `!=` operator. But, why? Isn't it enough to overload `==` and `!=` is automatically the opposite (in truth value) of `==`?

Shouldn't the result of one imply the other automatically?

Comment: Say you have `x = 1` and `y = 2`, it is indeed useless to do `if x == 1 and x != 2`, however checking `if x == 1 and x != y` is another story, if there is the possibility of `x = y`.

Comment: Imagine a filter in an ORM for a database. With both operators overloaded there can be different SQL generated for them.

Comment: Note: This isn't a _bad_ question. With a little rephrasing, this is a good question highlighting a particular design feature of python.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't *have* to, python isn't forcing you to. In fact, the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__) explains the what and why:

> By default, `__ne__()` delegates to `__eq__()` and inverts the result
>   unless it is `NotImplemented`. There are no other implied relationships
>   among the comparison operators, for example, the truth of (`x<y` or `x==y`) does not imply `x<=y`.

In general, the truth of `x==y` does not have need to imply that `x!=y` is false. If your data model needs to reflect this relationship, python lets you do so with minimal headache.

Note that for earlier versions of python, not even this relationship was implied. For example,

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.val == other.val

f1, f2 = Foo(1), Foo(1)
```

Now, `f1 == f2` returns `True` on any version. HOWEVER,  `f1 != f2` returns `False` on python-3.x, but `True` on python-2.x (because `__ne__` is not implied on python-2.x, and in general two user defined objects are not equal if their IDs are not the same, i.e., not the same object).

Comment: Thnx. I didn't even check the documentation. My bad. Thank you.

Comment: `In general, the truth of x==y does not have need to imply that x!=y is false.` Can you give an example when such a model might be useful?

Comment: @Truth-seek I may not be the best person to answer that question, but take a look at this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50548843/why-overload-both-equality-and-inequality-operator/50548858#comment88108500_50548843) by Klaus D.